# Google Spreadsheets, match/lookup in ALL rows, except the current one

Tags: google-sheets

Google Spreadsheets, match/lookup in ALL rows, except the current one

I have never come across a method that looks in all rows, except the current.

Say you have a `match` or `vlookup` and it looks in ALL the rows except the current one the formula is in.

We use a formula like below that verifies if a certain value already exists (using a MAX), but if it finds itself then the match or vlookup is always 1 (or in error)

```
A   B
1   Formula: Does value 1 from cell A1 exist in column A? 
2   Formula: Does value 1 from cell A2 exist in column A?
3   Formula: Does value 1 from cell A3 exist in column A?
4   Formula: Does value 1 from cell A4 exist in column A? Check all except row 4
```

Something like this

```
Formula in cell C4: match(A4;A$1:A3&A5:A)
Or Formula in cell C4: match(A4;A:A&[^A4])
```

Comment: Do you need the row that value is in, or just to check if it appears anywhere else in the range?

Comment: Do you have to use Match/Lookup? What do you use MAX for? Please give more details, or preferably an example output for column B.

Comment: I think the question is more along the lines of "how does one check a column for values but skip the row/cell we are currently in". Can one for example concatentate ranges as a new range? (take A1:A4 + A6:A => so taking the whole column A except for A5)

Comment: Update your question to give an example of output for Column B and check the answers and comment on them stating why they don't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula from the second row of data onward (B2=):

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(A2,A$1:A1,0),MATCH(A2,A3:A,0)+ROWS(A$1:A1)+1)
```

If there is no match above the current cell it will search for a match below, and will return the correct index in the full column range by adding `ROWS(A$1:A1)+1` to the *below* match result.

Copy this formula downward from B2 to B3 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to check whether the value appears in the column except for the current row just use COUNTIF()

Put this formula in B2

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF($A$2:$A="",,IF(COUNTIF($A2:$A,"="&$A2:A)>1,True,False)))
```

Otherwise please specify what kind of output you want